# Solving: $y (1-y) / (y') ^2 \leq x (1-x) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Im interested in the differential equation:

$ \frac{y  (1-y)}{(y') ^2} = x (1-x) $

Clearly $y=x$ and $y=1-x$ are solutions. In general, if $y$ is a solution, so is $1-y$.

Indeed I want to show that there is NO solution to the ineqaulity
$$ 0\leq  \frac{y  (1-y)}{(y') ^2} \leq  x (1-x) \text{ for all } x \in [0,1] $$
and
$$ 0\leq \frac{y  (1-y)}{(y') ^2} <  x (1-x) \text{ for some } x \in [0,1] $$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying both sides by $ (y') ^2 $ we get
$$ y  (1-y) = (y') ^2 x (1-x) .$$
By arranging terms and taking square root, we get
$$ \sqrt{ y  (1-y)} = \frac{dy}{dx} \sqrt{x (1-x)} .$$
Hence we have
$$ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x (1-x)}} = \frac{dy}{\sqrt{ y  (1-y)}} .$$
By integrating both sides, we have
$$ - 2 \arcsin (\sqrt{1-x})=- 2 \arcsin (\sqrt{1-y}) + Constant .$$
Hence
$$ \arcsin (\sqrt{1-x}) +  C =\arcsin (\sqrt{1-y}) .$$
Taking $\sin$ of both sides:
$$ \sqrt{1-y} =\sqrt{1-x} \cos(C) + \sqrt{x} \sin(C) .$$
Notice that $C=0$ leads to $y=x$ and $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$ leads to $y=1-x$ solutions. Taking square of both sides,
$$ 1-y =(1-x) \cos ^2(C) + x \sin^2(C) + 2 \sqrt{x(1-x)} \cos(C) \sin(C) .$$
are solutions candidates. For $C = \pi/4, $ we get
$$ 1-y =(1-x) \frac{1}{2} + x \frac{1}{2} + 2 \sqrt{x(1-x)} \frac{1}{2} .$$
Hence $$ y = \frac{1}{2} - \sqrt{x(1-x)} $$
satisfies the equality. Hence $$ y = \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{x(1-x)} $$ is a solution for the equality too.

Following the same lines for inequality:
$$ y  (1-y) \leq (y') ^2 x (1-x) .$$
By arranging terms and taking square root, we get
$$ \sqrt{ y  (1-y)} \leq \frac{dy}{dx} \sqrt{x (1-x)} .$$
Hence we have
$$ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x (1-x)}} \leq \frac{dy}{\sqrt{ y  (1-y)}} .$$
By integrating both sides, we have
$$ - 2 \arcsin (\sqrt{1-x})\leq- 2 \arcsin (\sqrt{1-y}) + Constant .$$
Hence
$$ \arcsin (\sqrt{1-x}) +  C \geq \arcsin (\sqrt{1-y}) .$$
Taking $\sin$ of both sides:
$$ \sqrt{1-y} \leq \sqrt{1-x} \cos(C) + \sqrt{x} \sin(C) .$$
Taking square of both sides,
$$ 1-y \leq (1-x) \cos ^2(C) + x \sin^2(C) + 2 \sqrt{x(1-x)} \cos(C) \sin(C) .$$
I could not figure out how to proceed.

Comment: This does not seem to answer your question. Should this be put into the post, instead of as an answer?

Comment: One could, but I did not want to make the post look long with the computation